# How to replace characters with Emojis when typing in UITextView objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, emoji, emoticons

I have a `UITextView`. I would like to know whether it's possible if I type a special characters like ":)", it gets converted it into a smiling Emoji automatically like in Android. Is it possible in iOS? Any help or a good suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look at `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method?

Comment: But how to convert the characters into emojis . .

Comment: Keep a list of "Emoji" you want to use and the characters you want to replace and replace them.

Comment: There are hundreds  of Emojis how it is possible to check for each one . .  it means that i have to use a lot of if-else if-else which is tedious work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

...to get a new string with a substring replaced (See NSString documentation for others)

Example use

```
NSString *str = @"This is a string";

myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"a" withString:@"\u2022"];
```